# OSX freezes after hard drive swap

Tags: macos

I've had a 13" MBP from late 2011 that I water damaged beyond repair. Today I bought a 2012 MBP, swapped out the optical drive for SSD that was on the old system(had the OSX in there), swaped out the main hard drive that was on old system as well as added back my 8gb of ram that was on old system.

None of these seem to of been damaged by the water(or so my tech guys said).

However once I boot into OSX, after 10-90 seconds current app freezes, I'm still able to use the mouse but nothing else responds.

Anyone could suggest any methods to trouble shoot this?

Thank you!

Comment: What operating system is on the old hard drive?

Comment: Did you try the safe mode? Does it work with only swapping 1 drive at the time.

Comment: I'm on lion, haven't tried removing any of the new hardware. Currently downloading the online recovery tools thing